# Render Engine For Low Poly Game Assets

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

What render engine should I use to create low poly game assets with basic diffuse color for unity, blender render or cycles render?

I was trying to create a simple shape with two materials having basic diffuse color only, but the second material don't export with the color I set in the cycles render.

So, does the blender render is the standard way to create low poly game asset like this?
[image]
source: https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/plant/leaf/low-poly-forest-assets

Comment: It's generally recommended to create the materials in whatever engine will be doing the rendering; in this case, unity. That said, for simple materials like this you *might* be able to get away with importing them, but I doubt it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57531/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using textures and you want the diffuse material to be transferred "as is" to Unity from Blender, use basic Blender Internal materials (no nodes). Cycles materials are not being transferred to Unity at all. If you're using textures, there is no such limitation, you can create the textures in any render engine of your liking.